# Can we say that String is an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm always confused when I hear strings are primitives in JS, because everybody knows that string has different methods like: length, indexOf, search etc.

```
let string = "Please locate where 'locate' occurs!";
let pos = str.lastIndexOf("locate");
let position = str.search("locate");
```

Comment: In JavaScript, everything is an `object`.

Comment: @randomSoul everything except primitive values

Comment: @Dmitry numbers have methods too ;) `(1.98346982746).toFixed(3)`

Comment: I think you're looking for this [Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)

Comment: A string has all the properties and methods that an object has. With duck typing a string is an object.

Comment: AFAIK strings are not objects they are native types like numbers but if you want to access the method on it they are boxed with String object.

Answer (score 5):

It's true that everything in JavaScript is just like object because we can call methods on it. When we use `new` keyword with string it becomes an object otherwise it's primitive type.

```js
console.log(typeof new String('str')); //object
console.log(typeof 'str'); //string
```

Now whenever we try to access any property of the string it box the the primitive value with `new String()`

```
'str'.indexOf('s')
```

is equivalent to

```
(new String(str)).indexOf('s').
```

The above process is called as "Boxing". "Boxing" is wrapping an object around a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are not objects, they are native types, like numbers, but if you want to access the method on it they are boxed with String object. The same happen with numbers you can call `(10).toString()` but in fact you're calling `toString` on `Number` instance that wraps 10, when you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Not certainly in that way.

If you try to use a class method for a primitive, the primitive will be temporarily wrapped in an object of the corresponding class ("boxing") and the operation will be performed on this object.
For example,

```
1..a = 2;
```

It's equal to:

```
num = new Object(1.);
num.a = 2;
delete num;
```

So, after executing the operation, the wrapper will be destroyed.

However, the primitive itself will remain unchanged:

```
console.log( 1..a ) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Every data type is a object in JavaScript.
String, array, null, undefined . Everything is a object in JavaScript